# Two versions of calculating the variance are equal

Tags: statistics, proof-writing

A course I'm taking defines the mean of a batch of data with the size $n$ like so:

$$\overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n}$$

And the unbiased sample variance:

$$s^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^2}{(n-1)}$$

And a second, equivalent way of calculating $s^2$:

$$s^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i) ^ 2}{(n -1)}) * \frac{1}{(n -1)}$$

Now, they didn't show any proof for this, so I thought I try my luck. Let's start with the first version and see what we can rewrite:

$$\begin{align}
s^2 &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})}{(n-1)} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 - 2\overline{x}x_i + \overline{x}^2)}{(n-1)} \\
&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{(n - 1)} - 2\overline{x} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{(n -1)} + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \overline{x}^2}{(n-1)}
\end{align}$$

Well, this is as far as I came.

Now, the middle term:

$$2\overline{x} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}{(n -1)}$$

I could *almost* rewrite as $2\overline{x}^2$, buuut that doesn't work because the definition of $\overline{x}$ includes dividing by $n$ and NOT dividing by $(n-1)$.

So, in my opinion, the proof can only work if we define:

$$\overline{x} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\color{red}{(n - 1)}}$$

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe a typo: The sample variance should be squared: $(x_i-\overline x)\to (x_i-\overline x)^2$

Comment: In addition, those are not equal unless the $\frac{(\sum_ix_i)^2}{n-1}$ in your second definition is actually supposed to be $\frac{(\sum_ix_i)^2}{n}$

Comment: @OnoL yes that is a typo, thanks!

Comment: @Max Whatever you got that second definition of $s^2$ from has a typo. See Robert Z's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unbiased sample variance should be 
$$
\begin{align}s^2 &= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \overline{x})^2}{n-1}
=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n-1}-2\overline{x}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n-1}+\overline{x}^2\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n 1}{n-1}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}{n-1}-2\overline{x}\frac{n\overline{x}}{n-1}+\overline{x}^2\frac{n}{n-1}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-n\overline{x}^2}{n-1}\\
&=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i)^2}{n-1}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: \begin{align} s^2 &= \frac{\sum_i x_i^2}{n-1} - \frac{n\bar{x}^2}{n-1} \\ &= \frac{1}{n-1}\left( \sum_i x_i^2 - n\bar{x}^2 \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{n-1} \left( \sum_i x_i^2 - \frac{\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2}{n}\right)\end{align} There appears to be a typo in the OP's course material.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote down the formula to hastily and got confused by it in the end. :-|  I don't understand this simplification though: $$2\overline{x}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{n-1} = 2\overline{x}\frac{n\overline{x}}{n-1}$$

Comment: And also here $... =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-n\overline{x}^2}{n-1} = ...$ where you put the sum together again, how can you do that, since the fractions where separate in the step before that?

Comment: By definition, $n\overline{x} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. Moreover $2\overline{x}\frac{n\overline{x}}{n-1}=\frac{2n\overline{x}^2}{n-1}$

Comment: @RobertZ thanks for the update, I can see it now. Somehow I got quite confused with this equation, I will try again. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the fact that sample variance is a biased estimator of variance. This is why we define a new unbiased estimator of sample variance as $S_{n-1}^2$.

$$S_{n-1}^2=\frac{n-1}{n}S_n^2$$

This perhaps explains why you think your mean should be redefined when in fact you are working with an unbiased estimator instead of normal sample variance.

So since all of your denomenators have $n-1$ instead of $n$, which I assume to be what you are looking for, perhaps the problem is that you are confusing $S_{n-1}$ with $S_n$

Comment: There is a denominator of $n-1$ in both given definitions of $s^2$.